# Alguém pode me dizer pq o if else não está retornando else?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Fala pessoal, vou tentar ser o mais esclarecedor possível na pergunta.
Seguinte: Tenho um if else que é feito por uma consulta pdo, quando eu digito um cpf existente ele faz o trabalho corretamente, até ai ok! Mas quando eu digito um cpf que não existe no banco de dados, ele deveria exibir o else, onde o mesmo não está fazendo isso, alguém pode me ajudar?

CODIGO

```
$acao  = (isset($_POST['acao'])) ? $_POST['acao'] : '';
$name  = (isset($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$indicated_by  = (isset($_POST['indicated_by'])) ? $_POST['indicated_by'] : '';
$password  = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$cpf   = (isset($_POST['cpf'])) ? str_replace(array('.','-'), '',         
$_POST['cpf']): '';
$telefone   = (isset($_POST['telefone'])) ? str_replace(array('(',')','','-'), '', $_POST['telefone']): '';
$data_cadastro   = (isset($_POST['data_cadastro'])) ? str_replace(array('.','-'), '', $_POST['data_cadastro']): '';
$password  = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$id_ind = (isset($_POST['id_ind'])) ? $_POST['id_ind'] : '';


$conexao = conexao::getInstance();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE cpf = ".$cpf;
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
$clientes = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach($clientes as $cliente):

    if($cliente->cpf === $cpf):
        CPF EXISTE


    else:
        CPF NÃO EXISTE

    endif;

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você faz uma busca no banco de dados procurando pelo CPF informado, logo se vc digitar um CPF que não existe na base o seu `select` não retornará nenhum registro, fazendo que não entre nem no `foreach`.

Você pode verificar diretamente se a consulta retornou algum valor, caso retorne o CPF existe, se não retornar nada o CPF não existe

```
$conexao = conexao::getInstance();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE cpf = ".$cpf;
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
$clientes = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if($clientes ):
    CPF EXISTE
else:
    CPF NÃO EXISTE
endif;
```

Dessa forma o `if` verifica se existe algum valor para a variável `$clientes`, se houver, o CPF foi encontrado, se não houver o CPF não existe.

Comment: Aaaah meu amigo, agr eu percebi onde eu estava errado... sendo que eu a via testado desse jeito, mas eu  não me atentei em reparar que eu estava fazendo uma comparação de informação no if. Tipo... eu estava fazendo assim no if:

if($clientes === $cpf)

Sem necessidade kkkkkkkkkk, mas agora funcionou.

Cara muito obrigado pela atenção ai, acho que o desgaste mental estava me atrapalhando em não reparar isso. Obg pela ajuda, vlw mesmo.